# In java network programming, is there a way to keep the Server side open even when the Client side shuts down?

Tags: java, network-programming

Suppose that we have a simple Echo client/server pair in Java. As I understand it, once one side of the socket breaks then the whole connection is gone.

But what if I want a Server that can always stay alive, even if the client side dies.  I want to be able to resume a broken connection.

Echo Server :

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // create socket
        int port = 4444;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.err.println("Started server on port " + port);

        // repeatedly wait for connections, and process
        while (true) {

            // a "blocking" call which waits until a connection is requested
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.err.println("Accepted connection from client");

            // open up IO streams
            In  in  = new In (clientSocket);
            Out out = new Out(clientSocket);

            // waits for data and reads it in until connection dies
            // readLine() blocks until the server receives a new line from client
            String s;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(s);
            }

            // close IO streams, then socket
            System.err.println("Closing connection with client");
            out.close();
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

any tips appreciated thanks

Comment: Read about TCP and UDP. With TCP it's not possible, you will have to handle the reconnect yourself. With UDP it's possible, but has other implications

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Reconnecting a broken connection is impossible, but there may be another way of doing what you want.

Comment: @tbodt - another way - hmm, like what ?>

Comment: If you're trying to resume a download, you'll need something special in your protocol so that when the connection is broken, the client can tell the server where it was so the server can start sending data in the right place. It really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: With TCP, at the fundamental level, you can't do that: **if the other end disconnect, then it's the TCP/IP implementation (in your operating system) that will close your side of the connection too. Your Java code can't do anything about that.** If you want to "resume" a previous connection, then you'll have to add the notion of a "session" and a "session state"/history to use when/if the other end connect again, as is suggested by an answer bellow.

Answer (score 10):

What you're missing is the concept of a 'session'.  Think about the position of a server, when some bits arrive 'on the wire'.  What to do with these?  With TCP/IP, there is some information already present on the wire, namely:

- src addr
- src port
- dest addr
- dest port
- *and* the message payload itself
- *and* some other stuff (like sequence counters, to ensure 'packets' are not jumbled during transmission)

The operating system of the server uses the src/dest addr/port information to decide if this is 'a conversation which is already in progress' or not.  Mainly it considers the `dest port` (since the message already made it to the machine itself, through the internet and the firewall) to decide if it is for your Java program listening on the 'dest port'.  However, it uses the entire src-addr/src-port/dest-addr/dest-port to try and deliver the payload to your program *in the order the sender sent them* (which might not be the order in which they arrived, because of the intervening inter-net).  Notice that a single 'message' might actually be split up into multiple packets.  Your operating system's TCP/IP stack is doing a fair bit of work for you.

However, notice that in order to perform this function on your behalf, the operating system has to devote some amount of resources to 'tracking the state' of the TCP/IP session.  At the very least, for each set of port/addr src/dest, there needs to be a counter of the last well-received 'packet', some buffer space to hold the packets until your program is ready to consume them, and so forth.

Now the question facing the TCP/IP stack implementor is "how long should I 'hang on' to this state for"?  Is 10 seconds enough? 20 minutes?  At some point, after not hearing from the client for a while, the session must 'timeout'.  If there were more packets to send in a sequence, and the client starts sending them again, the server has to be able to say "sorry, you're sending me packet 234 of some previous message, but because I didn't hear from you for a while, I threw out packets 1-233.  Could we start again?".

So in that sense, there's no way to prevent the client from 'disconnecting'.  Sure, you can keep listening on the socket, in case the client recovers and sends some more data.  But you and your client will need a way to 'pick up where we left off'.

In HTTP, that's achieved using a 'session cookie' - a long unique string that the server gave to the client, and the client re-sends with each fresh request (whether it happens over the same TCP-level session or not).  This is an 'application level session' which has a lifetime longer than that of the TCP session.

Since you're writing an application, and it sounds like you have some degree of control over what the client and server get to say to each other (the 'protocol'), you have more options about how you will agree on what is a session, how to deal with things if the client 'goes away' (timeout the session), and how both sides will recover and 'pick up where we left off' (re-establish the session).  Don't forget about authentication will you!

As others have said, it depends a great deal on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to create a Server and multiple Clients, what we normally do is to create a Thread responsible for the communication between the server and one of the clients, so everytime a client connects to the server, the server will start a new Thread and will give it the corresponding socket.

The code should be something like this:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<ClientHandler> clientHandlersList = new ArrayList<ClientHandler>();

        // create socket
        int port = 4444;
        boolean isOver = false;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.err.println("Started server on port " + port);

        // repeatedly wait for connections, and process
        while (!isOver) {

            // a "blocking" call which waits until a connection is requested
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.err.println("Accepted connection from client");

            ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(clientSocket);
            handler.start();
            clientHandlersList.add(handler);
        }

        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

And the ClientHandler Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private boolean disconnect = false;


    public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while(!disconnect){
                Object message = readMessage();

                //DO something
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object readMessage(){
        try {
            Object obj = in.readObject();
            return obj;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void writeMessage(Object obj){
        try {
            out.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect(){
        try {
            disconnect = false;
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a worthy and helpful answer (+1).  It's a fair example of how to handle multiple requests arriving on the socket.  It doesn't *directly* address the question of 'how do we pick up where we left off' but gives a good framework for doing so.  NB. instead of sub-classing `Thread`, implement `Runnable` and do `(new Thread(myRunnable)).start()`.   NB(2). the 'thread per request' design is generally thought not to 'scale' well (ie. >100's concurrent requests), and there are other designs.  (cf. NodeJS for the opinions, vert.x for the Java). NB3. HTTP gets past firewalls, has 'Cookies'.

Comment: @DavidBullock - I was curious about the vert.x , for Java.  Is this something that can be done in a single machine?  I will look up about this one now

Answer (score 4):

As someone pointed out, you can't do this with TCP.

Here is a simple example of a `DatagramSocket` (UDP) echo server.

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class UDPEchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        new ServerThread().start();
    }


    static class ServerThread extends Thread
    {

        protected DatagramSocket socket = null;

        public ServerThread() throws IOException
        {
            this("ServerThread");
        }

        public ServerThread(String name) throws IOException
        {
            super(name);
            socket = new DatagramSocket(4444);

        }

        public void run()
        {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[256];

                    // receive data
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);

                    // send back the response to the client at "address" and "port"
                    InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
                    int port = packet.getPort();
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
                    socket.send(packet);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Added test info

You can test it with `nc`

```
[gustaf@gustf-air]$ nc -u 127.0.0.1 4444
testing echo server
testing echo server
killing it now
killing it now
^C
[gustaf@gustf-air]$ nc -u 127.0.0.1 4444
now we are back
now we are back
```

Comment: Ok this looks pretty neat . btw ,   I'm using Windows  . I think code is made  on Linux/Mac's  ?  `[gustaf@gustf-air]$ nc -u 127.0.0.1 4444` When I tried to run `java UDPEchoServer 4444` it gave an error `Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
        at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)`  , thanks !

Comment: Hi, the `BindException`might be because you already have your "old" program running. Ports can not be shared. Just change `4444` to something else you know is not in use. Yes, you are right I am using a mac.  There is probably a similar command for windows, but I do not know which. But it would be a simple thing to just write a client yourself. Here is a good tutorial from oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html

Answer (score 0):

With using the socket api as shown in your code, this should not be a problem.
For a single connection if either side is being closed (or e.g. dies)
the complete association is "down" and can no longer be used.
This is what is happening with clientSocket from your code.

However, serverSocket still is open and accepting new connections. 
With respect to this, your server always "stays alive".

So, your shown code is plain vanilla example of socket api usage, for creating a server that waits for incomming connections and dispatches the individual (incomming) calls for being processed.

The only "downside" of your code is that by doing processing in the same thread as the accept(), your server will not be able respond to new requests
as long as it is processing the previos one. To avoid this processing could be
delegated to a new thread (as other pointed out already).

You might find additional explanation with documentation on accept().
e.g. you may read through [Socket API explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)

Please recognize, this is not directly a Java question. Java just envlopes and provides to Java programs the functionality of the underlying operating system with respect to socket communication. This is mostly what is 
documented as part of Posix standard, actually this is (with respect to sockets) just repeating (and aggregating) what has been specified with various RFCs (see  https://www.ietf.org/rfc.html for details of this specifications).

With sockets keeping a connection open (functioning to the full extent) after one side terminates it, is not possible if the socket is set to using TCP protocol. There is - just to add for completness - a mechanism (shutdown) for declaring the local sending side to be down while still accepting further data for input. (But I'd assume we are not talking about that very special feature.)
Keeping a connection open when the connected side is refusing to talk would cause logical problems and also would be a nightmare for resource management.
(How long would the server keep the resources?)

The standard pattern for using TCP with a daemon (a process that is continuously providing a service at a given port), is by means of accept() as indicated above:

- The daemon is looping on accept().
- a client is calling connect() to the server
- accept() is returning a new (dedicated) connection for communicating with the client
- client and server exchange data
- one side (client or server) is terminating the connection.

The strategy the server is using for executing several requests
(synchronous processing one after another, request queues, one thread per connnection is a completley separate design decision. It depends on degree of parallelism, available resources, etc.

The server will have two different "kinds" of sockets in use:

1. the socket it is calling accept() on is the one the server is "listening" for incomming connections.
   This socket is the one that is continuously open.
2. a socket returned from accept() is for a specific connection.
   This is used for communicating with a specific client and is going to "die"
   at the end of the interaction.